# Align choices to width

Tags: tasks

I want to align the question options to the width of the column
[image]
**Like this:**

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,9pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlength{\taskindent}
\settowidth{\taskindent}{\hspace{0.09cm}\text{m)}}
\settasks{
    item-indent=\taskindent,
    label-format=\MakeUppercase, 
    after-skip = 3ex,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols*}{2}
\begin{enumerate}[left=0pt,label=\bfseries\arabic*.,ref=\arabic*,resume]
\item 
\begin{justify}
        \textbf{I want to align options to width but not aligned as seen} 
\end{justify}
\begin{tasks}(5)
                \task $1$
                \task $2$
                \task $3$
                \task $4$
                \task $5$
            \end{tasks}
\end{enumerate}
\vfill\null
\columnbreak

\begin{enumerate}[left=0pt,label=\bfseries\arabic*.,ref=\arabic*,resume]
\item 
\begin{justify}
        \textbf{I want to align options to width but not aligned as seen} 
\end{justify}
\begin{tasks}(5)
                \task $1$
                \task $2$
                \task $3$
                \task $4$
                \task $5$
            \end{tasks}
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tasks` package will typeset each item in a fixed-with box, like

```tex
<tasks>    ::= <fwd-item> (<item-sep> <fwd-item>)*
<fwd-item> ::= \hbox to <some-fixed-width>{<item>}
```

hence changing it to

```tex
<tasks>.   ::= <item> (\hfill <item>)*
```

requires considerable patching.

But you can simulate the desired effect by picking an appropriate value for `column-set=<length>`, as far as the remaining line width (divided by the number of items per line) is wide enough to typeset each item text. For example, with `column-sep=3em` (and `debug` to draw bounding boxes),

```tex
\documentclass[a4paper,9pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlength{\taskindent}
\settowidth{\taskindent}{\hspace{0.09cm}\text{m)}}
\settasks{
    item-indent=\taskindent,
    label-format=\MakeUppercase, 
    after-skip = 3ex,
    debug
}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols*}{2}
Default:
\begin{enumerate}[left=0pt,label=\bfseries\arabic*.,ref=\arabic*,resume]
\item 
  \textbf{I want to align options to width but not aligned as seen} 
\begin{tasks}(5)
    \task $1$
    \task $2$
    \task $3$
    \task $4$
    \task $5$
\end{tasks}

\settasks{column-sep=3em}%
Setting \verb|column-sep=3em|:

\item 
  \textbf{I want to align options to width but not aligned as seen} 
\begin{tasks}(5)
    \task $1$
    \task $2$
    \task $3$
    \task $4$
    \task $5$
\end{tasks}
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Compared to [@CarLaTeX's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/622309) which uses `itemjoin` and inline list envs from `enumitem` package,

- When the width of item text changes (but still fit in the allowed max width of an item), `tasks` ensures items in different multi-choice questions vertically aligned, while inline list envs don't have this feature.
- When the width of item text is large enough, `tasks` will wrap the text in lines by the width of item width, while inline list envs will wrap the whole list by the width of line width.

Comment: It partially worked for me, thank you. Can we enter a generic column-sep value? affecting the entire document? So that automatically aligns the options to the column width? @muzimuzhi Z

Comment: @Pitaya88 Sure, you can set `column-sep` globally like how you set `item-indent` and the similar.

Comment: How? I tried but it goes beyond the width @muzimuzhi Z

Comment: \setlength{\columnseprule}{1.7pt}
\setlength{\columnsep}{1.2cm}

Comment: Add `column-sep=<length>` to your existing `\settasks{
    item-indent=\taskindent,
    label-format=\MakeUppercase, 
    after-skip = 3ex,
}`

Comment: Correct me if I misunderstood "enter a generic column-sep value".

Comment: thank you sir...

Answer (score 3):

You may use `enumerate*` from `enumitem` package:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,9pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols*}{2}
\begin{enumerate}[left=0pt,label=\bfseries\arabic*.,ref=\arabic*,resume]
\item \bfseries I want to align options to width but not aligned as seen

    \begin{enumerate*}[before*={\noindent},label=\Alph*), font=\normalfont,itemjoin=\hfill]
                    \item $1$
                    \item $2$
                    \item $3$
                    \item $4$
                    \item $5$
    \end{enumerate*}
\end{enumerate}
\vfill\null
\columnbreak
\begin{enumerate}[left=0pt,label=\bfseries\arabic*.,ref=\arabic*,resume]
\item \bfseries I want to align options to width but not aligned as seen

    \begin{enumerate*}[before*={\noindent},label=\Alph*), font=\normalfont,itemjoin=\hfill]
                    \item $1$
                    \item $2$
                    \item $3$
                    \item $4$
                    \item $5$
    \end{enumerate*}
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If your lists are always like that you can set them with `\setlist[enumerate,<levels>]{<format>}`.